# how to remove parameter from url when redirecting to get method in `Java`

Tags: java, jsp

I want to remove the parameter from url which is coming from `HeaderInterceptor.java` in `postHandle` method when I load the get method after redirect from post method.

What is written in my `HeaderInterceptor.java` file is

`modelAndView.addObject("roleId", stu.getRoleId());`

So, when I redirect from post method to get , the url which come is: 
`http://localhost:8080/System/StudentList.htm?roleId=23`

So, here I want to remove is `?roleId=23`.

Following is the code written in POST method:

`String referer = request.getHeader("referer");
return "redirect:"+referer;`

But I m not able to see any parameter in referer string.

The code I tried in POST method is :
`RedirectView redirectview = new RedirectView("?");
redirectview.setExposeModelAttributes(false);`

but it is still showing the same url with parameter.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can manually remove the URL parameters by calling something like 
`String newURL = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?"));`

Comment: When I try to trace the URL in get method, I dont get any like `?roleId=23`

`String url = request.getServletPath();`

So how can I remove it manually by using substring operation